# How to send the strongly typed model object from VIEW to CONTROLLER

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

Hi I have a strongly typed VIEW in MVC.

The Model renders all data in the VIEW.

How can I send the Model object from this view with all the data to a controller on form submit.

**CONTROLLER 1** which sends the Model object

```
return View(CurrentUser);
```

**VIEW** which receives the Model object

```
@model WebApp.Models.UserEntity

 <h4><b>Contact Information:</b></h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h4><b> Name:- @Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName </b></h4>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h4><b> Address1:- @Model.Address1</b></h4>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h4><b>Address2:- @Model.Address2</b></h4>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h4><b> Attention:- @Model.Attention</b></h4>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h4><b> City:- @Model.City</b></h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4><b> State:- @Model.StateName</b></h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4><b> Zip:- @Model.Zip</b></h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4><b>HomePhone:- @Model.HomePhone</b></h4>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4><b>CellPhone:- @Model.CellPhone</b></h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

How to send this Model along with the data to CONTROLLER 2 as a parameter??

Please help suggestions and any approach feasible.

Comment: As they are all read-only fields, why would you not just send back a primary key for the UserEntity? Also where is your form? That might clarify your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to

- enclose the view contents in a form that posts to Controller2.
- add something to the form (text boxes, hidden fields, etc) to contain the model properties
- add a submit button

I am wondering why you are doing this, though.  It seems odd to post data to another controller instead of an action on the same controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller2")
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
     ...
}
```

Comment: From the comments I understand that there is no way to send the complete model object back with the properties.

Comment: By "instead of an action on the same controller" you mean like POST or GET?

Comment: Since once user submit this form I will be rendering a different view based on the confirmation of this data.

Comment: You do not need a second controller just to render a different view.  Multiple actions on the same controller can (and usually do) return different views.

Answer (score -1):

You have very poor understanding of technologies you are using. Please study some HTML and basics of HTTP if you want to use asp.net MVC - you really cant do it otherwise.

There is no way (well, no sane way) to send model from view to controller. View is rendering HTML. If you want controller to receive some data, that is whole another request - which your browser will create when you submit form. This form shall contain all the data you want controller to receive, and therefore you must do this in handing of previous request (as you do in your example - but not HTML headers elements, but form elements.

Comment: Yes I am new to MVC forgot to mention that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being new. But why dont you read and try some basic tutorials before you ask questions which really dont make sense?

Comment: like this : http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/ or this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios